# selenium WebDriver javascript

Tags: selenium-webdriver

please suggest me a book or tutorial for selenium testing in javascript a link or some thing
//below code is just for quality of post website is not allowing to post only above query

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = require('selenium-webdriver').By,
    until = require('selenium-webdriver').until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
driver.quit();
```

Comment: If you are asking for a recommendation or tutorial then I am afraid this is not a right place, or, if you are facing a specify issue please clarify the question more we will try to help you

Comment: how can i rum my js for web deriver i searched web n installed node.js and mocha how can now i run the above script

Comment: Question is not clear to me. But, a good tutorial is right there on the Selenium website - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp